# Protractor for Angular application : E/launcher Process exited with Error code 199 - Chrome hangs up with data:

Tags: protractor

I am new to using Protractor. I ran the sample Protractor code- Chrome is invoked but hangs and E/launcher Process exited with error code 199.

These are the tools and versions I have installed.

> npm - 6.4.1
>   Protractor - 5.4.1
>   Webdriver -12.1.0
>   chromedriver 2.42
>   selenium server standalone -3.14.0

I have also installed the latest JDK and JRE files.

**Spec.js** file:

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
    it('should have a title', function() {
        browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Super Calculator');
    });
})
```

**Conf.js** file

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['spec.js'],
    framework: 'jasmine',
};
```

I tried options like `Direcconnect: true` and `useAllAngular2AppRoots: true`, but the hanging problem doesn't stop. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include the full error message?

Comment: Hell Ben, thanks for looking into my question. I just figured out what was the issue. The chrome version that was installed in my machine was > 69. I installed the latest version of chrome and was able to execute the test. It worked.

Comment: Glad you got it working